# Angular2 dynamic form checkbox

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement dynamic form in Angular2 and I have gone through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html but it has components only for text box and dropdown, I have to populate my dynamic form with check boxes and radio buttons, not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create new checkbox control and include it in the dynamic form.

1. Create new checkbox control named app/question-checkbox.ts as:

   ```
   import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

   export class CheckboxQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
       controlType = 'checkbox';
       type: string;

       constructor(options: {} = {}) {
           super(options);
           this.type = options['type'] || '';
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add new question item

   ```
   new CheckboxQuestion({
           key:'agree',
           label:'I Agree',
           type: 'checkbox',
           value:'false',
           order: 4
       })
   ```
3. Include it in the dynamic form

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pR2iPAjQuFvFw3UFzRGM?p=preview) works for me.

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks for your help, but here you are consuming data from one of your components but I have to consume data from API, that is where I am facing problem with...       @Meligy