# How to manage a checkbox inside an Augular dynamic form?

Tags: angular

I have some problem making a checkbox works in a dynamic form using Angular 4.

On firefox, when checking the checkbox, the value I get is `'on'` in place of `true`. And when unchecking it, the value is still there and not set to `false` or `''`.

On chrome, it doesn't even seem to work...

I have created an example bases on the [Angular  dynamic form tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

I have added a new file named `question-checkbox.ts` to manage a checkbox:

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class CheckboxQuestion extends QuestionBase<boolean> {
  controlType = 'checkbox';
  type: string;

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.type = 'checkbox';
  }
}
```

Then, I have updated the `dynamic-form-question.component.html` to use this new type:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <input *ngSwitchDefault [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" />
  </div>
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

And, I have updated the dataset in `question.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownQuestion } from './question-dropdown';
import { QuestionBase }     from './question-base';
import { TextboxQuestion }  from './question-textbox';
import { CheckboxQuestion }  from './question-checkbox';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  getQuestions() {

    let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [

      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          { key: 'solid', value: 'Solid' },
          { key: 'great', value: 'Great' },
          { key: 'good', value: 'Good' },
          { key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven' }
        ],
        order: 3
      }),

      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'firstName',
        label: 'First name',
        value: 'Bombasto',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      }),

      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'emailAddress',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'email',
        order: 2
      }),

      new CheckboxQuestion({
        key: 'sideksick',
        label: 'Sidekick',
        order: 3
      })
    ];

    return questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
}
```

Lastly, I have updated the `dynamic-form.component.html` to display the current state of the form:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
      <df-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></df-question>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p><strong>Current state</strong><br>{{form.value | json}}</p>
</div>
```

[Example available on Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/fmgXPPJfyoG1c7x790Q9/)

So my question would be: How should I do to be able to use checkboxes inside an Angular 4 dynamic form, and be able to get a correct value?

As for why I need to use a dynamic form, it is because I am generating my form based on a JSON coming from an outside service which describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New answer

It seems there is a really strange behavior which cause this problem with Angular 4.x.

Writing this won't work:

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="'checkbox'" />
```

But writing this does work:

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" type="checkbox" />
```

The only difference is that we don't use Angular template functionalities (`[type]="question.type"`, `[attr.type]="question.type"` or `type={{question.type}}`) to write the content of `type`, and so we only use the native `type` from HTML.
This seems like a bug to me...

Here the [fix on Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/yCs0kI6ksHJhCcVvDLIC/).

---

## Old answer

***The solution above is the only one you should consider.***

I found an hint from the answer of [angular2-dynamic-form-checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008897/angular2-dynamic-form-checkbox).

I was missing the following part in the file `dynamic-form-question.component.html`: `[(ngModel)]="question.value" (change)="question.value = ckb.checked" #ckb`.

```
<select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
  <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
</select>
<input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" [(ngModel)]="question.value" (change)="question.value = ckb.checked" #ckb />
<input *ngSwitchDefault [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" />
```

It seems that in the case of a dynamic form, checkboxes aren't manage automatically, and so we need to update their value on `change` in function of the `checked` state of the checkbox.

Here the [fix on Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/j5H7LgEQyMczCK588etn/).