# How to create component template for check boxes in angular dynamic form

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms

I am doing dynamic form by referring this link  [click here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms)
and its working for all textarea, multi select and date type. But for checkbox not working
while submitting the form I am getting the out put like the below

```
{"name":"df","food":"Pizza","description":"zx v","color":["Red"],"incidentdate":"2017-09-22","options":true,"gender":"Female","submit":null}
```

In this how I can identify which checkbox is selected?
here just showing "options":true

I have tried in the below format but its not working.

```
template: `<div 
      class="dynamic-field form-input" 
      [formGroup]="group">
       <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
       <span *ngFor="let option of config.options">        
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="config.name" value="{{option}}" />{{option}}        
      </span>        
    </div>`
```

Please let me know am I doing anything wrong?

Here is the config

```
this.config =     
        {
            "label" : "Title",
            "type" : "input",
            "name" : "title"
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Status",
            "type" : "select",
            "name" : "status",
            "options" : [ 
                "Accepted", 
                "Rejected", 
                "Pending", 
                "Complete"
            ],
            "placeholder" : "Select an option"
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "What options?",
            "type" : "checkbox",
            "name" : "question",
            "options" : [ 
                "Option D", 
                "Option E", 
                "Option F"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Incident Date",
            "type" : "date",
            "name" : "incidentdate"
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Comments",
            "type" : "textarea",
            "name" : "comments"
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Description",
            "type" : "textarea",
            "name" : "descriptions"
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Is it good?",
            "type" : "radio",
            "name" : "gender",
            "options" : [ 
                "Male", 
                "Female"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Who is responsible?",
            "type" : "multiselect",
            "name" : "responsible",
            "options" : [ 
                "Manager", 
                "Supervisor", 
                "Site-Supervisor"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "label" : "Submit",
            "type" : "button",
            "name" : "submit"
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: What is the error ? cannot get checkbox value ?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: while submitting its  not showing which checkbox is selected. For other types its working

Comment: Do you have prepared working example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: no i dont have that in online. but i can share you my code

Comment: Can you at least add your config for dynamic form?

Comment: I have updated the question please check

Comment: `But for checkbox not working while submitting the form` You was talking about `question` field?

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654514/how-to-manage-a-checkbox-inside-an-augular-dynamic-form?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @heart yes What options? label

Comment: For more details, you can have a look at here https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#question-model

Answer (score 1):

When i deal with group of checkboxes i prefer creating FormArray of group to handle it.

For example if we want to declare array of checkbox with the following values:

```typescript
[ 
  "Option D", 
  "Option E", 
  "Option F"
]
```

We  can create `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s like:

**dynamic-form.component.ts**

```typescript
createControl(config: FieldConfig) {
  ...
  if(config.type === 'checkbox') {
      return this.fb.array(
        config.options.map(x => {
          return this.fb.group({
            name: x,
            value: value ? value.indexOf(x) > - 1 : false
          })
        }));
  }
```

then template should be changed to

**form-checkbox.component.html**

```typescript
<div class="dynamic-field form-input" [formGroup]="group">
  <ng-container [formArrayName]="config.name">
    <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
    <span *ngFor="let option of config.options; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">        
      <input type="checkbox" [name]="config.name" formControlName="value"  />{{option}}
    </span>    
  </ng-container>   
</div>
```

When we'll print value of our form it will look like:

```typescript
{
  "question": [
    {
      "name": "Option D",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Option E",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Option F",
      "value": false
    }
  ]
}
```

This way we can easily manipulate the values we want to pass to the server during submitting:

```typescript
handleSubmit(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  const result = {...this.value};
  Object.keys(result).forEach((key, index) => {   
    if(this.controls[index].type === 'checkbox') {    
      result[key] = result[key].filter(x => x.value).map(x => x.name);
    }
  })
  this.submit.emit(result);
}
```

in this case it will submit:

```typescript
{
  "question": [
    "Option D",
    "Option F"
  ]
}
```

in some other cases we would want to pass id or something complex value.

See also **[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydvzdk?file=app%2Fdynamic-form%2Fcomponents%2Fform-checkbox.component.ts)**

Comment: Cannot find control with path: 'options -> 0' shows error in console

Comment: Can you reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: what is the use of field interface

Comment: let me try stackblitz . I have not used it before. For me it will take time

Comment: i am new in angular. Please let me know if i did any mistakes

Comment: Your example doesn't work and i don't see `createControl` method there. Please compare it with my example

Comment: I have updated the code. but still its not showing what i expect. Its showing { isTrusted: true }

Comment: Where did you do it? Can you post link?

Comment: on the same link