# Can I use formArrayName on ng-container element?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Is it possible to use an Angular form attribute - like formArrayName - on the ng-container element? I would like to write it like this:

`<ng-container formArrayName="funds">`

And then I would put my select element inside ng-container. I know ng-conainer is not rendered as an element in DOM but does it interfere handling such form attributes used on it?

Comment: What is the problem with it? Did you try it?

Comment: It is not rendered in HTML, opposite to other formControlName attributes and so on. I wonder if it is good practice to do so and if it won't affect functionality of my form.

Comment: I suspect it should work

Comment: I used it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357561/how-to-create-component-template-for-check-boxes-in-angular-dynamic-form/46704827#46704827